# What is the best way to create an object out of interface in typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have been using typescript from 1 years and every time I need an object to pass, I need to do it in ugly way or manually.

In typescript there are interfaces for type definition and holds all the parameter we need. Is there a way we can create object out of it?

example:

```
export interface User {
  name: string;
  email: string;
}
```

I want below code to be automated which I cannot do it from interface rater I have create a class with constructor.

```
user {
 name: ''/null/undefined,
 email: ''/null/undefined
}

let user: User = new User() // this will show error
```

But I can create a new object out of below class.

```
export class User {
  constructor() {
    name: string;
    email: string;
  }
}

new User();
```

Which one is batter? creating a constructor class or interface?

Comment: What do you mean by "I want code to be automated"? Do you want to assign value to the interface directly without creating an implemented class?

Comment: Yes. is that possible?

Comment: You can also create it using object literal syntax: `let user: User = { name: '', email: '' };`. Obviously you are the only one who can determine which is better because you're the one who is complaining about the way it's done normally.

Comment: This way I know it. is there other way? if there are 30 properties in my interface i need to write them all. as all are there in my interface, is there a way i can write something simpler not like  `let user: User = { name: '', email: '' .........};`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is a way.

Interface and class are two different thing and have different use cases. Interfaces are just structure and cannot have a instance, You you will see the compiled typescript which is generated JavaScript, you will not find interfaces anywhere.

So the interfaces are only at compile time and not run time.

But the classes are run time. So when you say new User(), it create instance of that class as it is there in the generated JavaScript.

you can also explore abstract class if it fits in your situation.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can assign value to the interface directly and by the looks of it if you do not need to assign/instantiate all the properties defined in the interface then you can mark them as optional using `?`. In the following example email, is marked as optional and the subsequent assignment of user will be a valid statement.

```
interface User {
  name: string;
  email?: string;
}

let user: User = { name: '' };
```

Comment: My question is different! I am trying to create object out of interface not optional parameters